# Django REST Framework Serializer and JSONRenderer enconding

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with serialization an JSON formating with Django REST Framework. I'm using SQLite3 in my Django project. When I serialize an object with a string containing non-ASCII characters, I get enconding problems.

For example, if I query my model directly, I get the string:

```
"Grados Centígrados"
```

After the serialization, the serialized.data is:

```
 u'Grados Cent\xedgrados'
```

So the serializer is doing

```
"Grados Centígrados".decode('UTF-8')
```

Then the JSONRenderer is 'encoding' the 'decoded' string again, giving the following as result:

```
'Grados Cent\xc3\xadgrados'
```

I can't manage to get a correct representation in a browser.

EDIT: I'm using Django REST framework 3. I added the following to my settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
),
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
)
}
```

Then I created the urls.py and views.py, following the steps in the tutorial:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/

I get: "Grados CentÃ­grados"

Comment: Using Django REST Framework 3.1.1 I do not run into this issue. It shows "Grados Centígrados" without an issue in the browsable API. Have you modified your `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting in your settings? Can you post that if so?

Answer (score 2):

Using Django REST Framework 3.1.1 I do not run into this issue. It shows "Grados Centígrados" without an issue in the browsable API. Have you modified your REST_FRAMEWORK setting in your settings? Can you post that if so?

Assuming you are on Django Rest Framework 2, you might run into this issue unless you are using the [UnicodeJSONRenderer](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/renderers#unicodejsonrenderer), which is different than the [JSONRenderer](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/renderers#jsonrenderer). In 3.0+, the `UnicodeJSONRenderer` is now called `JSONRenderer`, thus always defaulting to display the string in ***unescaped*** utf-8 encoding.

## From the 2.0 documentation:

### [JSONRenderer](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/renderers#jsonrenderer)

> Renders the request data into JSON, using utf-8 encoding.
>
> Note that non-ascii characters will be rendered using JSON's \uXXXX character escape. For example:
>
> `{"unicode black star": "\u2605"}`

### [UnicodeJSONRenderer](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/renderers#unicodejsonrenderer)

> Renders the request data into JSON, using utf-8 encoding.
>
> Note that non-ascii characters will not be character escaped. For example:
>
> `{"unicode black star": "★"}`

Thus, you would want to have this in your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.UnicodeJSONRenderer',
    ),
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. I Edited my first post with more information.

Answer (score 2):

The `UnicodeJSONRenderer` class no longer exists ([in version 3 of Django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#unicode-json-by-default))

It is included by default. If you want it disabled, paste the following in your settings.py file

`REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'UNICODE_JSON': False
}`

Answer (score 1):

Write your own UTF-8 render:

> file: `your_app/renders/__init__.py`:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

class UTF8JSONRender(JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'
```

And in your settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'your_app.renders.UTF8JSONRender',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```